# Toggling the animated value in order to fade in/out the view

Tags: react-native, animation

I'm trying to toggle view's opacity with animated value, by handling the button click, but I'm not getting the desired result, except the first time button is clicked, it fades out (opacity = 0) but when I press the button again nothing happens and I can't see my view. Here's the code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    animation: new Animated.Value(1)
  }
  startAnimation = () => {
    const { animation } = this.state
    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: animation === 0 ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 1000
    }).start()
  }
  render() {
    const animatedStyle = {
      opacity: this.state.animation
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]} />
        <Button title="Toggle fade" onPress={this.startAnimation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
} .
```

Does anybody know what am I doing (understanding) wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you don't change the state for your animated values, and this `const { animation } = this.state` will have always the same value, and `toValue: animation === 0 ? 1 : 0,` will have the same value too. I try to show you how I did this in my projects, but you have to update it for your needs.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    animation: new Animated.Value(1),
    isVisible: false   //add a new value to check your state
  }
  startAnimation = () => {
    const { isVisible } = this.state
    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: isVisible === 0 ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 1000
    }).start(() => {
         this.setState({ isVisible: !this.state.isVisible });//set the new state, so the next click will have different value
    })
  }
  render() {
    const animatedStyle = {
      opacity: this.state.animation
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]} />
        <Button title="Toggle fade" onPress={this.startAnimation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
} .
```

I am using this:

```
let val = this.state.sliderOpen ? 0.8 : 0;

    Animated.timing(                  // Animate over time
      this.state.sliderAnimation,            // The animated value to drive
      {
        toValue: val,                   // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
        duration: 5,              // Make it take a while
      }
    ).start(); 
 this.setState({
   sliderOpen : !this.state.sliderOpen 
})
```

Maybe try to extract the value to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but it's still not working, I even tried to put this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ isVisible: !prevState.isVisible })) inside the callback of start() method but with same results. There's something else and I can't figure out it..

Comment: I think we miss something, I am using this in my project and it is working... I will take a look again.

Comment: If you have a working example can you please share it in a snack? thanks!

Comment: Great, and those articles you found are great too. What was the issue we missed ?

Comment: I think is the `setState` after `start()`. Please consider ti to mark as good answer, maybe other people will got the same issue and they will know this is working.

Comment: Yes it is, but I’ve made two minor modifications, the first one is to use setState with previous state, not directly toggling, as React team claims its a bad practice; and the second thing it’s better to put set state inside the completion handler of start() method where you can check if animation really finished. Together we are better :)

Comment: Yep, true. I saw that setState in `start` completion handler in your articles below, really usefull. I will update with this the answer, to give a better solution to other peoples. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @oma I was able to get it work, here's the snack:
[Toggle opacity in React Native](https://snack.expo.io/@brascene/toggle-opacity)

Besides that, I've found a nice article on this where this feature can be reused:

[Animating appearance and disappearance in React Native](https://goshakkk.name/react-native-animated-appearance-disappearance/)

And here's the snack of the working example, with slight modification.

[Animate opacity](https://snack.expo.io/@brascene/animate-opacity)

This solution looks pretty well, hope you can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a node package [react-native-fade-in-out](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fade-in-out) that toggles a view's opacity with an animated value. You can look at the source code to see how it is accomplished, but here's a simplified version:

```js
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {Animated} from 'react-native';

export default class FadeInOut extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(this.props.visible ? 1 : 0),
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.visible !== this.props.visible) {
      Animated.timing(this.state.fadeAnim, {
        toValue: prevProps.visible ? 0 : 1,
        duration: 300,
      }).start();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.View style={{...this.props.style, opacity: this.state.fadeAnim}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```